# Attach existing root volume to ec2 spot instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to attach an existing volume to an ec2 spot instance during setup so it can boot from it?

I have only manages to attach ebs volumes as a secondary volume, but I would like to set the boot volume so I can persist changes to the boot volume as well without having to create an image.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't attach existing EBS volumes as root to EC2 Instances while setup. After setup you can attach a volume to that instance. BlockDeviceMapping allows you to specify size or snapshotid, both won't work here, because you requirement is want to attach it as root.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to define a root volume is by using an AMI.

It is possible to *swap* volumes on a normal instance:

- Stop the instance
- Detach the volume
- Attach the other volume
- Start the instance

**Updated:** This is now possible on Spot instances too.

Comment: Actually, we can now stop spot instance. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-ec2-spot-can-now-stop-and-start-your-spot-instances/